# Placing a button according to background

Tags: android, xml

I have an activity that looks like this:

[image: activity ui]

When I run the app on the emulator, the pushpin is not over the post-it note, so I know there will be problems with different sized screens. The post-it note and cork board are the background. How could I go about making it so that, on any sized screen, the pushpin will be at the correct location? It's currently a linear layout.

Comment: why not posts some code on what you've already tried?  It's more likely to attract answers

Comment: I've only tried messing around with layout weights, I'm mostly looking for ideas to try, not necessarily solutions.

Comment: Trust me, the most convenient idea for you would be to use the RelativeLayout because you use the other views as reference points and due to that you can place them conveniently anywhere you like. I'm also assuming you will want to place text within the postit, with relativelayouts, you can place views ontop of one another with reference points. And yes, do use weights for convenient resizing on other devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution for you is use a RelativeLayout. I advise that your post-it note not be a part of the background but an own ImageView so that you may re-size it any time to fit any screens. And due to that you can then add this to your code for your cork.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/cork"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/postit_note"
/>
```

It will center the cork in the center and align it to the top of the post-it note.

You may view all the other attributes to help you with RelativeLayouts [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above recommendation, do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/postit"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/angry_btn"
                android:background="@drawable/pushpin"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:shadowRadius="5"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Note: You should make the brown part as the background for the outermost layout, and have a separate image for the post-it note, which you should set to the image view I have shown above.